# width not set after Transform.scale

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Unable to change the width after "Transform.scale"?

In the following sample code, the red Container, do not change width after setting fitWidth(width of container) when pressing the floatingbutton.

Only if it is les than MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

// State

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  Matrix4 matrix = Matrix4.identity();
  double fitWidth;

  @override
  void initState() {
    fitWidth = 0;
    super.initState();
  }

  double getSizeWidth(BuildContext context) {
    if (fitWidth != 0) {
      return fitWidth;
    } else {
      return MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    }
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var sizWidth = getSizeWidth(context);
    print(sizWidth);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Sample Code'),
        ),
        body: Transform.scale(
          scale: 0.5,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            width: sizWidth,
            height: 400,
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              fitWidth = 800;
            });
            // Add your onPressed code here!
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: may I ask why'd you create a function just to get the width of the device? you could just do var sizWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width; in your build

Answer (score 2):

its works for me

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        print(sizWidth);
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Sample Code'),
            ),
            body: Transform.scale(
              scale: 0.5,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                width: fitWidth != 0?fitWidth:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: 400,
              ),
            ),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  fitWidth = 800;
                });
                // Add your onPressed code here!
              },
              backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            ));
      }
```

cheers...

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}


class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  Matrix4 matrix = Matrix4.identity();
  double widthScale = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  double getSizeWidth(BuildContext context) {
    if (widthScale != 0.0) {
      return widthScale;
    } else {
      return 1.0;
    }
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Sample Code'),
        ),
        body: Transform(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          transform: new Matrix4.identity()..scale(getSizeWidth(context), 0.5),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 400,
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              widthScale = 0.5;
            });
            // Add your onPressed code here!
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice suggestion, but I need the width to be bigger after scaling - not scaling the width - if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Give alignment(`Align`)

```
Transform.scale(
  scale: 0.5,
  child: Center(  // or Align
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      width: sizWidth,
      height: 400,
    ),
  ),
)
```